# Does forgetting that one is fasting invalidate the fast?

Tags: sawm

I was told that for Ramadan sawm, if one accidentally forgets that they are fasting and eats, the fast is still valid.

However, does this apply if one accidentally eats during a voluntary (nafilah) or vow (nazar) sawm?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forgot I am fasting and realized after eat almost a meal](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25926/forgot-i-am-fasting-and-realized-after-eat-almost-a-meal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This applies to all sawm as the hadith this is based upon is general in wording:

> The Prophet (Allah bless him and give him peace) said, “Whoever
>   forgets that he is fasting and eats or drinks, then he still completes
>   his fast. It is only Allah who fed him and gave him drink.” [Bukhari]
>
> In another narration, the Prophet (Allah bless him and give him peace)
>   said, “If a fasting person eats forgetfully, it is only provision
>   Allah put forth to him and there is no makeup upon him.” [Bukhari]

Further details can be found [here](http://www.ummah.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-270426.html) and [here](http://seekersguidance.org/ans-blog/2010/08/28/accidental-forgetful-breaking-of-the-fast-what-is-the-difference/).

Comment: Those sites are quite unreliable and don't show which hadith exactly, but I found one similar to the first quoted one in Bukhari (Volume 3, Book 31, Number 154):  "If somebody eats or drinks forgetfully then he should complete his fast, for what he has eaten or drunk, has been given to him by Allah."