# Forgot I am fasting and realized after eat almost a meal

Tags: hadith, sawm, reference-request

I started my first day of shawal's 6 days fasting, alhamdulaylah, but in the middle of the morning I totally forgot that I was fasting because I was so busy in the work that I ate at least two bananas, a handful of grapes and drank half cup of water... I realized I was fasting when I was going to eat more...

I know Allah is the most forgiving for unintentional eating or drinking during fasting. But I think I did way over just a quick accident, though, I do admit that I was eating all those food **without** knowing that I was fasting. I wonder if I can still continue fasting?

Please cite authentic Quran / Hadith reference to back your analysis, otherwise, please do not answer with just your opinions. Jazak Allah Khair.

Comment: You see those questions to your right under the "Linked", just flagged 4 similar questions as dups to this question. This comment is to remind you to "search well before you ask".

Comment: @azam I guess it's just the amount I ate is really big that I feel it is almost like I ignored my fast for those time. So I want to double check does it matters the amount I ate and duration. However the answers helped.

Answer (score 5):

If you had the intention in the morning.

> "There is no fast for the one who does not intend to fast before dawn."
>
> Reference     : Sunan an-Nasa'i 2338
>
> Grade    : Sahih (Darussalam)

Then forgot that you were fasting.

> ‘Whoever forgets that he is fasting, and eats or drinks is to complete
>   his fast, as it was Allah who fed him and gave him something to
>   drink." Agreed upon.
>
> Al-Bukhaari (6669) and Muslim (1155)

Another

> “Whoever breaks his fast in Ramadaan by mistake does not have to make up that day or offer expiation.”
>
> Ibn Khuzaymah (1999)
>
> Classed as hasan by al-Albaani in Saheeh Ibn Khuzaymah.

Ruling : http://islamqa.info/en/50041

Comment: One should add that the translation by islamQA in the second hadith; where it is translated to "by mistake", the arabic word for that is "نَاسِيًا" which likely mean "forgetfully" as in the first hadith (translated to forgets), using the same verb "نَسِيَ" . The same word "nasiyan" is used in this [hadith](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/83/47) and translated to "forgetfully"

Answer (score 0):

Actually, my wife found something pretty legit inshaAllah.
Basically, I can continue fasting and still count as valid, alhamdulaylah, Allah is the most merciful :)

All reference in the link below:
http://islamqa.info/en/214153